# How can I get all the request headers in Django?

Tags: python, django, http-headers, httprequest

I need to get all the Django request headers. From what I've read, Django simply dumps everything into the `request.META` variable along with a lot of other data. What would be the best way to get **all** the headers that the client sent to my Django application?

I'm going use these to build a `httplib` request.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) `request.META` is a "standard Python dictionary containing all available HTTP headers". If you want to get *all* the headers you can simply iterate through the dictionary.

Which part of your code to do this depends on your exact requirement. Anyplace that has access to `request` should do.

**Update**

> I need to access it in a Middleware class but when i iterate over it, I get a lot of values apart from HTTP headers.

From the documentation:

> With the exception of `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE`, as given above, any `HTTP` headers in the request are converted to `META` keys by converting all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores and ***adding an `HTTP_` prefix to the name***.

(Emphasis added)

To get the `HTTP` headers alone, just filter by keys prefixed with `HTTP_`.

**Update 2**

> could you show me how I could build a dictionary of headers by filtering out all the keys from the request.META variable which begin with a HTTP_ and strip out the leading HTTP_ part.

Sure. Here is one way to do it.

```
import re
regex = re.compile('^HTTP_')
dict((regex.sub('', header), value) for (header, value) 
       in request.META.items() if header.startswith('HTTP_'))
```

Comment: I need to access it in a Middleware class but when i iterate over it, I get a lot of values apart from HTTP headers.

Comment: Thanks Manoj. Just out of curiosity - could you show me how I could build a dictionary of headers by filtering out all the keys from the `request.META` variable which begin with a `HTTP_` and strip out the leading `HTTP_` part. Is this possible through lambda functions? (I think they're called lambda functions) I'm asking this because I would probably go on do it the long way by first iterating over them, then checking to see if it begins with a `HTTP_` and then adding it to the new dictionary. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Manoj. I modified it slightly to use `lstrip('HTTP_')` instead of the regex. :)

Comment: @Mridang: `lstrip`. Of course. My substitute fu is weak today evening.

Comment: This does not seem to work with agents like CURL. It appears CURL is not setting the META dictionary while typical browsers do.

Comment: @Mridang Agarwalla: `lstrip` won't actually do what you're asking it to do.  `lstrip` will strip out all leading characters that match any characters in the string you give it, so if you have a header `"HTTP_TOKEN_ID"` it will give back `"OKEN_ID"`, because the `"T"` at the beginning of `"TOKEN"` matches a character in the string passed to lstrip.  The way to do it is `prefix = 'HTTP_'; header = header[len(prefix):]`.

Comment: I'll be using the headers for a new request, treating Django as a proxy and I was worried about the headers being all upper-case. Turns out HTTP headers are case-insensitive, so this isn't an issue.

Comment: Django 2.2 has supported `HttpRequest.headers`.

Answer (score 67):

Starting from Django 2.2, you can use `request.headers` to access the HTTP headers. From the [documentation on HttpRequest.headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers):

> A case insensitive, dict-like object that provides access to all HTTP-prefixed headers (plus Content-Length and Content-Type) from the request.
>
> The name of each header is stylized with title-casing (e.g. User-Agent) when it’s displayed. You can access headers case-insensitively:
>
> ```
> >>> request.headers
> {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6', ...}
>
> >>> 'User-Agent' in request.headers
> True
> >>> 'user-agent' in request.headers
> True
>
> >>> request.headers['User-Agent']
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
> >>> request.headers['user-agent']
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
>
> >>> request.headers.get('User-Agent')
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
> >>> request.headers.get('user-agent')
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
> ```

To get all headers, you can use `request.headers.keys()` or `request.headers.items()`.

Answer (score 19):

This is another way to do it, very similar to **Manoj Govindan**'s answer above:

```
import re
regex_http_          = re.compile(r'^HTTP_.+$')
regex_content_type   = re.compile(r'^CONTENT_TYPE$')
regex_content_length = re.compile(r'^CONTENT_LENGTH$')

request_headers = {}
for header in request.META:
    if regex_http_.match(header) or regex_content_type.match(header) or regex_content_length.match(header):
        request_headers[header] = request.META[header]
```

That will also grab the `CONTENT_TYPE` and `CONTENT_LENGTH` request headers, along with the `HTTP_` ones. `request_headers['some_key]` == `request.META['some_key']`.

Modify accordingly if you need to include/omit certain headers. Django lists a bunch, but not all, of them here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Django's algorithm for request headers:

1. Replace hyphen `-` with underscore `_`
2. Convert to UPPERCASE.
3. Prepend `HTTP_` to all headers in original request, except for `CONTENT_TYPE` and `CONTENT_LENGTH`.

The values of each header should be unmodified.

Comment: That can all be combined into a single regexp, `re.compile(r'^(HTTP_.+|CONTENT_TYPE|CONTENT_LENGTH)$')`

Answer (score 18):

Simply you can use [HttpRequest.headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.headers) from [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) onward. Following example is directly taken from the official [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/) under [Request and response objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#module-django.http) section.

```py
>>> request.headers
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6', ...}

>>> 'User-Agent' in request.headers
True
>>> 'user-agent' in request.headers
True

>>> request.headers['User-Agent']
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
>>> request.headers['user-agent']
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)

>>> request.headers.get('User-Agent')
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
>>> request.headers.get('user-agent')
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6)
```

Answer (score 7):

request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
`/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py`

you can get that from this file though...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any easy way to get only HTTP headers. You have to iterate through request.META dict to get what all you need.

django-debug-toolbar takes the same approach to show header information. Have a look at **[this file](http://github.com/dcramer/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/panels/headers.py)** responsible for retrieving header information.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, it appears your intent is to use the incoming HTTP request to form another HTTP request. Sort of like a gateway. There is an excellent module [django-revproxy](https://django-revproxy.readthedocs.io/) that accomplishes exactly this.

The source is a pretty good reference on how to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get client key from request header, u can try following:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework import exceptions
from apps.authentication.models import CerebroAuth

class CerebroAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
def authenticate(self, request):
    client_id = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
    if not client_id:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Client key not provided')
    client_id = client_id.split()
    if len(client_id) == 1 or len(client_id) > 2:
        msg = ('Invalid secrer key header. No credentials provided.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
    try:
        client = CerebroAuth.objects.get(client_id=client_id[1])
    except CerebroAuth.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No such client')
    return (client, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware to use "-" instead of "_" in header Key

Because if you use "Current_User" in header, you can not get it by

```
request.headers.get('Current_User')   <-- None
```

user "xxx-xxx" as the key

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>request.META</b><br>
{% for k_meta, v_meta in request.META.items %}
  <code>{{ k_meta }}</code> : {{ v_meta }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```