# How to print all recieved post request include headers in python

Tags: python, django

I am a python newbie  and i have a controler that get Post requests.
I try to print to log file the request that it receive, i am able to print the body but how can i extract all the request include the headers?
I am using request.POST.get() to get the body/data from the request.

Thanks

Comment: If this is in `django`, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889769/how-can-i-get-all-the-request-headers-in-django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get all the request headers in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889769/how-can-i-get-all-the-request-headers-in-django)

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure that this what i am looking for. i don't know what i have in the header this is what i try to find out.

Answer (score 0):

To get request headers, you can use [request.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), as it returns dictionary containing all available HTTP headers.

```
headers = request.META
```

Answer (score -1):

request.POST should give you the POST body if it is get use request.GET
if the request body is json use request.data

Comment: I don't need the body, i want the headers. The body i can get.