# DRF: making my gateway forward incoming request with InMemoryUploadedFile to next service

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What is the correct way to just route a front-end request (that used to work) through a gateway to a service (that used to work). (Even now, if I send the front-end request strait to the service everything still works, so it it just my gateway view that is not handling and forwarding the request properly)

My front-end used to post images with user posts to my back-end just fine. But I have implemented a gateway and now the only thing I am still struggling with is just forwarding a file that the user posts to the required service:

All my gateways just `json.dumps()` the incoming request data and moves on, but with the image I get an error along the lines of: `TypeError: Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable` - which I perfectly understand, but what is the correct way to send the image along to the service?

My gateway view:

```
class DailyReportImages(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = INSERT_DAILY_REPORT_IMAGE
        res = requests.post(url, headers=request.headers, data=json.dumps(request.data), files=request.files)
        return Response(res.json(), res.status_code)
```

This is what I have for now after days of searching, and at least it reaches the backend now, but it still gives almost every error in the book depending on how I tweak it...

```
res = requests.post(url, headers=request.headers, data={"name": "test", "report": "myreport"}, files={'Screenshot from 2020-01-06 19-04-33.png': request.FILES["image"]})
```

For instance service complains that the `name/report` values are empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

a minimal verifiable example is here,

```
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class DailyReportImages(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

        cleaned_headers = {
            header_name: header_value for header_name, header_value in request.META.items() if
            type(header_value) == str
        }
        if cleaned_headers.get('CONTENT_TYPE') == 'application/json':
            res = requests.post(url, json=request.data, headers=cleaned_headers)
        else:
            # we must send as `multipart/form-data`
            data_if_any = request.POST.dict()
            files_data_if_any = request.FILES.dict()
            composed_data = {**{key: (None, value) for key, value in data_if_any.items()}, **files_data_if_any}
            res = requests.post(url, files=composed_data, headers=cleaned_headers)

        return Response(res.json(), res.status_code)
```

---

#### Why the current code does not work?

The [**`request.data`** -- (DRF doc)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)  *may* contains the ***uploaded files*** which is a [*`InMemoryUploadedFile`*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile) type and is not JSON Serializable.

**Note:** The OP's code snippet will not raise a *"TypeError: Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable"* error if there is no file object in the payload/request-data

### References

1. You can use the [**`json`**](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) parameter of `requests` library to send ***`dict` like object***
2. [How to send `multipart/form-data` using `requests` module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35974071/12578202)
3. [How to convert **`QueryDict`** (or `MultiValueDict`) to a `dict` object?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict)
4. [How can I get all the request headers in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889769/how-can-i-get-all-the-request-headers-in-django)

Comment: Thank you! Excellent answer and 100 pts well spend - code works nicely now  :)

Comment: Glad that worked!! Please go through the references too, that might useful for you. Also, please do *upvote* the answer if you feel the answer is useful :)