# How to find out the client browser type in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display a message telling the user to use Google Chrome or Firefox, but I want this message to appear only if they are using Internet Explorer. How can I find out what kind of browser a user has?

I know the http request contains such information (the request header). But how do I get this information in Django?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889769/how-can-i-get-all-the-request-headers-in-django) help?

Comment: FYI, there are many, many, *many* more browsers than the ones you mention.

Comment: Use user agent field of leader and parse that.